# How can I design wireframe from a 2D image?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a camera image of a building. I want to design 3D wireframe of building. I want to identify floors of building in image. How can I do this? If I cannot suggest some option from which I can design same building using some tool so that I can get wireframe or anyway by which I can identify floors of building. On hovering mouse over floor whole floor should be highlighted.

Comment: @WestLangley May I know the reason to remove WebGL link?

Comment: Because it is not a webGL programming question.

Comment: hmm, not even a javascript question really. Learn to model in Blender (or other 3d tool) then import it to three.js and then write some javascript.

Comment: I thing that what you need is a map of the image. And, I believe it will be in 2-D